# How can I create an object array and save that array in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to web development and just started out using the MEAN-Stack. I am glad for any help I can get.

**I got the following problem in short:**

- I got an $scope array like this

  $scope.alerts = [{...},{...}{...}]
- From this array, I would like to post two values inside each object to MongoDB with mongoose

**Now the Problem in more specific terms.**

I have an array with object like shown below:

AngularJS Controller Snippet

```
$scope.alerts = [
    { id: 1,
      title: 'someTitle1',
      weighttitle: 'someWeightTitle1',
      value: 1,
      weight: 30,
      options: {
        showTicks: true,
        hidePointerLabels: true,
        hideLimitLabels: true,
        stepsArray: [
            { value: 1, legend: 'Very poor' },
            { value: 2, legend: 'Very poor' },
            { value: 3, legend: 'Fair' },
            { value: 4, legend: 'Very poor' },
            { value: 5, legend: 'Average' }

        ]
      }
    },
    { id: 2,
      title: 'someTitle2',
      weighttitle: 'someWeightTitle2',
      value: 1,
      weight: 60,
      options: {
        showTicks: true,
        hidePointerLabels: true,
        hideLimitLabels: true,
        stepsArray: [
            { value: 1, legend: 'Very poor' },
            { value: 2, legend: 'Very poor' },
            { value: 3, legend: 'Fair' },
            { value: 4, legend: 'Very poor' },
            { value: 5, legend: 'Average' }

        ]
      }
    }
];
```

And I have the part in the Controller that creates the object for mongoose

Also in the same AngularJS Controller as code above

```
var article = new Articles({
    title: this.title,
    someTitle1: {
      value: this.value,
      weight: this.weight,
    }
  });
```

The `title: this title` works as intended and creates a database entry but the someTitle does not.

At this point, it would be good to **allow some Array to be written in MongoDB**.

My Schema for this scenario looks like listed below:

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  someTitle1: {
    value: Number,
    weight: Number
  }


});

mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

I am wondering if it is not possible

Comment: Do you want to save objects in mongodb on front end without sending them to server? Or you missed write server side code?

Comment: I left the server sided code out. Since it works for the title already. I would like to know how I can write arrays into mongo